# I want to understand how passport js work specially req.user and how data is populated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am new to node js and tried passport for authentication, i found it hard to understand the work flow.
so my question is what is actually `req.user` where it came from ?
is it something constant related to passport and can't be changed to anything else like `req.profile` ?

Secondly in the following html code

```
  <p>
  <strong>id</strong>: <%= user._id %><br>
  <strong>username</strong>: <%= user.local.username %><br>
  <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.local.password %>
  </p>
```

From where html is populating `user` object, neither my database schema nor my passport contain the word `user`

This is my database schema

```
  local:{
    username : String,
    password : String
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: req.profile came from the serialization you did with passport and the strategy you extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show you where `req.user` comes from without using passport. First thing you need to understand is a `middleware` in express is just a function that takes in `request`, `response` and a `next function`.

let's say I have an endpoint:

POST `/auth/login` that takes a `username` and `password`.

This endpoint could return an `access token` (random string generated by you and stored on the database, if you don't want to store on your database you could look into JWT).

Ok, now that you have that access token after login success.

You can pass it along with other requests to your server. 
Let's say another endpoint:

GET `/auth/profile` which is protected and only can be access with the right `access token`.

But what is protecting the route? It's a `middleware`.

Below we define a `checkAuth` middleware.

```
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
   // here I can retrieve accessToken from the request header 
   const accessToken = req.get('accessToken')
   // with this accessToken I can query the database and check if this access token is correct or not
   findUserWithTheAccessToken(accessToken)
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
          // Here's the answer to your question where `req.user` comes from.
          req.user = user
          next() // call next() so it can go to the request handler
        } else {
          throw new Error('Invalid access token.')
        }
      })
}

// then your router would look something like the following
router.get('/auth/profile', checkAuth, handler) // implement your handler ☺️
```

You can always check express website to learn more.

Comment: So `req.user` is something internally made by passport, what about the html 
`<strong>username</strong>: <%= user.local.username %>` from where doest it get user object or how the backend send this to the frondent to be populated ?

Comment: That'd be a template engine, if I'm correct that syntax is ejs I think.

Comment: Basically, You use res.render('page', { user: { local: { username: "John" } } }) to populate data on the view.

Answer (score 0):

`passport`=>   Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js. and its easy to implement.

> login page send username and password to passport.
>
> It will check with your database which is configured by you.
>
> get success then the passport will store user details into `req` session form that you can retrieve it wherever you want by using your `req`